How to create a long table with page breaks in LaTeX?
I am trying to create a long table in LaTeX with six columns and two rows. The first row is for the header items, and the second row contains very long texts, which cause the table to need to break across pages. I developed the following code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,article,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hdivide={10mm,*,10mm},vdivide={16mm,*,10mm}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{helvet} % Pacote para usar a fonte Helvetica
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Define a fonte padrão como sans-serif (Helvetica)
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightSkyBlue}{RGB}{184, 204, 228}
\definecolor{LightOliveGreen}{RGB}{155, 187, 89}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{placeins} % Pacote para controle de barreiras de flutuação

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Ajusta a altura das linhas

\OnehalfSpacing

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove a linha superior do cabeçalho
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lcr}
            \begin{minipage}[l]{0.18\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[]{educa_mais_logo}
            \end{minipage}
            &
            \begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
                \centering
                \textbf{SECRETARIA DE EDUCAÇÃO DO ESTADO DO MARANHÃO} \\
                \textbf{SECRETARIA ADJUNTA DE EDUCAÇÃO PROFISSIONAL E INTEGRAL} \\
                \textbf{SUPERVISÃO DOS CENTROS DE EDUCAÇÃO EM TEMPO INTEGRAL} \\
            \end{minipage} &
            \begin{minipage}[r]{0.18\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gov_ma_seduc_logo}
            \end{minipage}
            %\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{PLANO DE ENSINO E DE APRENDIZAGEM ANUAL} \\
        \colorbox{green!70!black}{\textbf{- 2024 -}}
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{center}
         \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightSkyBlue}\textbf{CENTRO EDUCA MAIS Y BACANGA}} \\ \hline
            \textbf{ÁREA DE CONHECIMENTO:} Ciências da Natureza & \textbf{COMPONENTE CURRICULAR:} Física \\ \hline
            \textbf{CARGA HORÁRIA ANUAL: 40h} & \textbf{PROFESSOR:} Alexsandro Lucena Mota \\ \hline
            \textbf{SÉRIE:}  (~X~) 1ª série (~~~) 2ª série (~~~) 3ª série & \textbf{TURMAS:} 100, 101\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\FloatBarrier % Força a tabela anterior a ser processada antes de continuar

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
            \hline % Define a cor de fundo da linha
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightSkyBlue}\textbf{COMPETÊNCIAS GERAIS DA ÁREA DE CONHECIMENTO}}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA 1:}\\[-1ex] Analisar fenômenos naturais e processos tecnológicos, com base nas interações e relações entre matéria e energia, para propor ações individuais e coletivas que aperfeiçoem processos produtivos, minimizem impactos socioambientais e melhorem as condições de vida em âmbito local, regional e global.\\[3ex]
            
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA 2:}\\[-1ex] Analisar e utilizar interpretações sobre a dinâmica da Vida, da Terra e do Cosmos para elaborar argumentos, realizar previsões sobre o funcionamento e a evolução dos seres vivos e do Universo, e fundamentar e defender decisões éticas e responsáveis.\\[3ex]
            
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA 3:}\\[-1ex] Investigar situações-problema e avaliar aplicações do conhecimento científico e tecnológico e suas implicações no mundo, utilizando procedimentos e linguagens próprios das Ciências da Natureza, para propor soluções que considerem demandas locais, regionais e/ou globais, e comunicar suas descobertas e conclusões a públicos variados, em diversos contextos e por meio de diferentes mídias e tecnologias digitais de informação e comunicação (TDIC).\\[3ex]
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

    
\begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{|p{0.16\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|p{0.17\textwidth}|p{0.17\textwidth}|p{0.16\textwidth}|}
            \hline \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue}
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{QUADRO ORGANIZADOR CURRICULAR}}\\
            \hline\hline \rowcolor{LightOliveGreen}
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{1º PERÍODO LETIVO}}\\
            \hline \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue}
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA \qquad ESPECÍFICA} & \textbf{HABILIDADES} & \textbf{UNIDADE TEMÁTICA} & \textbf{OBJETOS DE CONHECIMENTO/CONTEÚDOS} & \textbf{SITUAÇÕES DIDÁTICO-PEDAGÓGICAS} & \textbf{ESTRATÉGIAS DE AVALIAÇÃO} \\
            \hline 
            \endfirsthead
            \hline \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue}
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{QUADRO ORGANIZADOR CURRICULAR}}\\
            \hline\hline \rowcolor{LightOliveGreen}
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{1º PERÍODO LETIVO}}\\
            \hline \rowcolor{LightSkyBlue}
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA ESPECÍFICA} & \textbf{HABILIDADES} & \textbf{UNIDADE TEMÁTICA} & \textbf{OBJETOS DE CONHECIMENTO/ CONTEÚDOS} & \textbf{SITUAÇÕES DIDÁTICO-PEDAGÓGICAS} & \textbf{ESTRATÉGIAS DE AVALIAÇÃO} \\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA 2:} Analisar e utilizar interpretações sobre a dinâmica da Vida, da Terra e do Cosmos para elaborar argumentos, realizar previsões sobre o funcionamento e a evolução dos seres vivos e do Universo, e fundamentar e defender decisões éticas e responsáveis.\newpage
            
            \vspace{1ex}
            
            \textbf{COMPETÊNCIA 3:} Investigar situações-problema e avaliar aplicações do conhecimento científico e tecnológico e suas implicações no mundo, utilizando procedimentos e linguagens próprios das Ciências da Natureza, para propor soluções que considerem demandas locais, regionais e/ou globais, e comunicar suas descobertas e conclusões a públicos variados, em diversos contextos e por meio de diferentes mídias e tecnologias digitais de informação e comunicação (TDIC).
            & 
            \textbf{EM13CNT204:} Elaborar explicações, previsões e cálculos a respeito dos movimentos de objetos na Terra, no Sistema Solar e no Universo com base na análise das interações gravitacionais, com ou sem o uso de dispositivos e aplicativos digitais (como softwares de simulação e de realidade virtual, entre outros).
            
            \textbf{EM13CNT301:} Construir questões, elaborar hipóteses, previsões e estimativas, empregar instrumentos de medição e representar e interpretar modelos explicativos, dados e/ou resultados experimentais para construir, avaliar e justificar conclusões no enfrentamento de situações-problema sob uma perspectiva científica.
            
            EM13CNT302: Comunicar, para públicos variados, em diversos contextos, resultados de análises, pesquisas e/ou experimentos, elaborando e/ou interpretando textos, gráficos, tabelas, símbolos, códigos, sistemas de classificação e equações, por meio de diferentes linguagens, mídias, tecnologias digitais de informação e comunicação (TDIC), de modo a participar e/ou promover debates em torno de temas científicos e/ou tecnológicos de relevância sociocultural e ambiental.
            
            EM13CNT303: Interpretar textos de divulgação científica que tratem de temáticas das Ciências da Natureza, disponíveis em diferentes mídias, considerando a apresentação dos dados, tanto na forma de textos como em equações, gráficos e/ou tabelas, a consistência dos argumentos e a coerência das conclusões, visando construir estratégias de seleção de fontes confiáveis de informações.
            & c& v& n& n\\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
\end{center}


    
\end{document}




However, the result was not as expected because the table exceeds the page limits and the content does not break to the next page.

I have an example of how the final result should look, but this example was made in docx.

How can I modify my code to achieve the expected result?

longtable can only break between rows, you can not use it for such a layout

What would be the correct way to do it, @DavidCarlisle?

that depends, as your image shows if you have different format in each column, there need be no shared baseline and so no shared breakpoint for each column.  I don't know of any generally available package that can do this
